# Exceeding token limit while maintaining context

Tags: python, openai-api, large-language-model, chatgpt-api, llm-context

I am using OpenAI's API to use gpt 3.5 as a chatbot via Python. Because I am making API calls, I understand that I need to maintain context and to do that, I need to pass the history of interactions each time to maintain context.

I do that by declaring an empty list.

```
prompt_messages = []
```

I pass in a system message, as well as prompt templates in the beginning. This is what it looks like:

```
# Function to call the OpenAI API
def process_gpt(file_prompt, system_msg):

    # Creates a list of dicts, declaring system message and file prompt
    prompt_messages.append({"role": "system", "content": system_msg})
    prompt_messages.append({"role": "user", "content": file_prompt})

    # Sending the list of dicts to chatgpt
    completion = client.chat.completions.create(model="gpt-3.5-turbo", messages=prompt_messages)

    # Getting the result
    nlp_results = completion.choices[0].message.content
    nlp_dict = {"role": "assistant", "content": nlp_results} # Turning the result into a dict

    # appending the result to the list of dicts
    prompt_messages.append(nlp_dict)

    sleep(8)
    return nlp_results
```

And to interact with the chatbot, I use this function, which appends to the list at each input and resubmits the entire list:

```
def bot(prompt):
  prompt_entry = {"role": "user", "content": prompt} # Turning out question to a dict
  prompt_messages.append(prompt_entry) # appending the question to our list of dicts

  # sending to chatgpt
  completion = client.chat.completions.create(model="gpt-3.5-turbo", messages=prompt_messages)

  # getting the answer from the model
  nlp_results = completion.choices[0].message.content
  print(nlp_results)

  # converting the answer to a dict
  nlp_dict = {"role": "assistant", "content": nlp_results}
  prompt_messages.append(nlp_dict) # appending to list of dicts
```

The problem here is that, as the chat continues, this grows larger and larger and at some point, I simply exceed the token limit.

Where am I going wrong? How can I maintain context without exceeding the token limit?

Comment: "This is obviously not how ChatGPT does it."  Provide evidence.  You've been grossly misinformed if you think any model just handles an arbitrary amount of context.  "Feel like my approach is highly inefficient" is an opinionated statement.  If you expect someone to be able to answer this you need to provide *concrete* verifiable details with an *unambiguous* question.

Comment: @possum
This is evidence: https://community.openai.com/t/how-to-preserve-the-context-session-of-a-conversation-with-the-api/324986
I feel like the question is pretty concrete but if there are mode details you'd like me to add, please let me know.